# How to make entity query condition field case insensitive to compared value

Tags: 8, nodes

I am writing an entity query as below

```
$entity_query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$entities = $entity_query->condition('my_field', 'some data', 'LIKE')
            ->condition('another_field', true)
            ->execute();
```

Here the field 'my_field' stores value as case sensitive data e.g. (Some Data). What I want is, how to make 'my_field' do a case insensitive comparison with (some data), however the data stored in this field is case sensitive. Hence it is not returning the desired record for me. Highly appreciate any help in this regard. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "CONTAINS" instead of "LIKE"?

Comment: Thanks, yes have tried that, but still it doesn't gives any record.